# Resolve promise on variable change to certain value

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, reactivex

I am writing an application using `reactivex` and `typescript` that controls a charging battery. I use a lot of promises here, which takes me to my question: I want a promise inside a chain to be resolved as soon as a variable (state of charge) reaches a certain value.

I tried using a `while` loop that checks the value periodically and returns as soon as it is reached, but this blocks the whole program.

```
private _performChargeJob(job: ChargeJob): Promise<any> {
    // Return a promise that is resolved if the job has finished processing.
    return this._performGoal(job.goals[0].goalId)
        .then(() => {
            this._handleCharge(this._soc, 100); // this is the important part where I'd wish the promise to resolve
        }).then(() => {
            this.logConsole("Finished charging.");
            this.callRosService({name: "set_charge_state", serviceType: "insystems_srvs/SetChargeState"}, {
                set_charge_state: 0,                 // stop charging
            });
        });
}

private _handleCharge(soc: number, maxSoc: number) {
// this function should return/resolve a promise when variable soc reaches 100.0
    this.logConsole("starting charge.");
    this.callRosService({name: "set_charge_state", serviceType: "insystems_srvs/SetChargeState"}, {
        set_charge_state: 1,                // start charging
    });
}
```

Here, I expect some kind of `watch()` (which is deprecated) or new `promise` that could wait for the value to reach that level. Maybe even an `observable`?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a getter/setter on that variable or observe the variable in some other way, whatever reactiveX gives you for this. A while loop is usually not a good solution to fix async issues, it's equivalent to polling.

Comment: I found [skipWhile](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skipwhile.html) for observables in reactiveX and will try that.

Comment: Is it the RxJS implementation that you use? Since reactivex seems to be for multiple languages with different syntax.

Comment: Yes, I use RxJS. I am using [this framework](https://coaty.io/) in particular, which uses observables a lot. Unfortunately, in my case, the promise in this chain is only thennable and catchable and does not support observable functions.

Comment: Can't you observe the `this._soc` variable alone and then use the .subscribe() method coaty gives you to resolve the promise?

Comment: I did something similar which works fine (apparently). I subscribed and checked a condition for the incoming data and only resolved the promise if the condition was true. It seems to work as expected.